# Avoid refreshing child update panel from parent updatepanel

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using master page. My contentplaceholder inside the UpdatePanel. In my contentpage
i keep the data. Some data are inside the another update panel. in contentpage there is
a button. When button click event fire then it refresh the child update panel also. I don't want this to happen. How can i achieve it?

```
Code
```

Master Page

```
<UpdatePanel>
   <asp:contentplaceholder id="c1">  </contentplaceholder>
<UpdatePanel>
```

Page

```
        <asp:content id="content" contentplaceholderid="c1">  
    // This button fire the event
               <asp:button> </asp:button>
    // Don't want to refresh this panel.
               <UpdatePanel id="childUpdatePanel" UpdateMode="Conditional">  
               </UpdatePanel>
        </asp:content>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use update panel like this

Master Page

```
<asp:contentplaceholder id="c1">  </contentplaceholder>
```

Page

```
   <asp:content id="content" contentplaceholderid="c1">  
   // This button fire the event
   <UpdatePanel>
           <asp:button> </asp:button>
   </UpdatePanel>
// Don't want to refresh this panel.
           <UpdatePanel id="childUpdatePanel" UpdateMode="Conditional">  
           </UpdatePanel>
    </asp:content>
```

Comment: I know we can remove update panel from MasterPage, But i don't want to do this. Is there any other way to resolve my issue?

Answer (score 0):

u can add one more content panel in master page like this

Master Page

```
   <UpdatePanel>
     <asp:contentplaceholder id="c1">  </contentplaceholder>
   <UpdatePanel>
   <asp:contentplaceholder id="c4">  </contentplaceholder>
```

Page

```
    <asp:content id="content" contentplaceholderid="c1">  

           <asp:button> </asp:button>

    </asp:content>

    <asp:content id="content" contentplaceholderid="c4">  
       <UpdatePanel id="childUpdatePanel" UpdateMode="Conditional">  
       </UpdatePanel>
    </asp:content>
```

Comment: Thanks, But i don't want to keep 2 place holders in masterpage.

Comment: No other solution because content which fall under updatepanel will refresh if any server side action happen under that update panel, one other solution is that u have to remove updatepanel and use jquery